# Getting error while adding data in json file using fileSystem in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

When I try to add simple data to a file with json extension using fileSystem in nodejs and this file is not created for me, I get an error.

[image]

The code I wrote is like this
I followed the instructions exactly, but I don't know why it doesn't work for me

```
const fs = require("fs");

let persons = [
    { id: "1", fullname: "example name 1" },
    { id: "2", fullname: "example name 2" },
    { id: "3", fullname: "example name 3" },
];

fs.writeFileSync("contacts.json" , persons);
```

I used **writeFileSync**, if I use **writeFile** it still gives the same error

---

**The version I am using for nodejs is 16.15.1**

Comment: You need to convert `persons` to a string: `JSON.stringify(persons)`